# Интерфейс Hamachi

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

А скажите **как или где** делать подобное в Visual Studio? Просто уж больно красиво.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF прекрасно подходит, не выходя из студии.

Если нужно еще круче - [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx)

Comment: WPF - можно расшифровку, и где его искать?

Comment: Windows Presentation Foundation http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPF